# Convert a converted bytes to str to bytes python

Tags: python, byte

How convert a converted bytes to str to bytes python
Simple:

```
re="Xin chào"
print(re.encode("utf-8"))
# OUTPUT : b'Xin ch\xc3\xa0o'
```

But i have a str like

```
print(new_str)
# OUTPUT : Xin ch\xc3\xa0o
```

So how can I decode "new_str" var

Comment: Looks like it's already encoded. Maybe you want to decode it?

Comment: Yes, i'm wrong in write

Comment: b'Xin ch\xc3\xa0o '.decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you meen "decode"? This is source

```
string = r"Xin ch\xc3\xa0o"
exec(f"global string;string=b'{string}'")
string = string.decode("utf-8")
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand what you were trying to do, but if you wanna encode a string or a variable use encode() function:

```
string = "string"
en = string.encode()
print(en)
```

for example:
if the string is "Hello", the output would be b'Hello'.

and if you wanna decode:

```
print (string.decode('utf8', 'strict'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your `new_str` var contains `b'Xin ch\xc3\xa0o'`
so,

```py
new_str = b'Xin ch\xc3\xa0o'
```

You can convert it back to `Xin chào` using the [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method.

```py
new_str = b'Xin ch\xc3\xa0o'
print(new_str.decode())
```

The output will be,
`Xin chào`